# "Field 'XXX' doesn't exist on type 'Query'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I am using a GraphQL API with a ruby on Rails backend for a client.

My problem is that my attributes work great in my graphQL interface, but I want to add an instance method of my model to my graphQL table.

According to the graphql-ruby [documentation](https://graphql-ruby.org/fields/introduction.html), I can call the object method directly and it should work as it would for an attribute, but it doesnt.

I also tried redefining the method in my InstalmentType class, this way :

```
module Types
  class InstalmentType < Types::BaseObject

    [...]

    field :revenue_tax_amount, Float, null: true

    def revenue_tax_amount
      object.revenue_tax_amount
    end

    self.apply_fields_description
    description self.get_description
  end
end
```

With or without redefining the `revenue_tax_amount` function, my queries return the following error :

`"Field 'revenueTaxAmount' doesn't exist on type 'Query'"`

Comment: do you have a`Types::BaseObject` defined?

Comment: Thanks For replies! The type BaseObject is defined and my queries on attribute fields work well in my graphql interface. However when I try to call instance methods, with or without redefining them in my type, I get the error

Comment: any chance your UI expects `revenueTaxAmount` but api is responding with `revenue_tax_amount `? In that case you might wanna do something like `field :revenueTaxAmount, Float, hash_key: 'revenue_tax_amount', null: true`